# How to determine and write value of BLE characteristic using flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to set value of specific characteristic in my BLE device using mobile device, but got some problem to identify this specific service and then to set value of it.

I am using `flutter_blue_plus 1.4.0` lib to find the devices and connect to specific one. This part is going pretty well and I am able to connect to the device, find services and theirs' characteristics. My device got 3 services, first one includes device info and I am able to read those values without any issues.

When it comes to the second service where I need to write value of one's of it's characteristics I face some problems. It turns out that service `UUID` an all of its' characteristics got the same `UUID`, so I can't find my specific characteristic this way. Because every characteristic in this service got some descriptor I came up with an idea to find it by the value of descriptor. However when I tried to read value of it the result is always the same on Android, on iOS the value is always empty...

Here is the part of code

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _connect();
    });
  }

  Future<void> _connect() async {
    try {
      viewModel.startLoading();
      await widget.bluetoothDevice?.connect(
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 15),
      );

      final services = await widget.bluetoothDevice?.discoverServices();
      if (services != null && services.isNotEmpty) {
        final deviceInfoChar = services
            .firstWhere(
              (element) => element.uuid.toString().contains('0000180a'),
            )
            .characteristics
            .firstWhere(
              (element) => element.uuid.toString().contains('00002a26'),
            );

        final customService = services.firstWhere(
          (element) => element.uuid
              .toString()
              .contains('00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'),
        );

        final versionByteList = await deviceInfoChar.read();
        final convertedVersionString = const Utf8Decoder().convert(versionByteList);
        print(convertedVersionString);
        //prints (1.5.0)

        for (int i = 0; i < customService.characteristics.length; i++) {
          final currentChar = customService.characteristics[i];
          print(i);
          print(currentChar.uuid);
          // prints 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb every time
          final descriptors = currentChar.descriptors;
          for (final BluetoothDescriptor d in descriptors) {
            final value = const Utf8Decoder().convert(await d.read());

            print(value);
            //Android prints value of descriptor from first characteristic every time
            //iOS prints empty string
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

So I decided to check this device using some already available app (LightBlue). Here is what I find out:

iOS:

[image: Light blue iOS app after connecting to the device]

Android: [image: Light blue Android app after connecting to the device]

So according to the screens it is probably possible to read all descriptors in a correct way.

The last thing I tried to do was jus hardcoding index of characteristic I want to change(17) and trying to write some value there, but also with no effect.

```
customService.characteristics[17].write([0x0, 0x0]);
```

I don't know is this some limitation of the `flutter_blue_plus` and I should check some other packages or focus on native solutions. Maybe it is caused by repeating `UUID` or I am doing something wrong here.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of BLE device are you trying to read from?